# Changing default color palette from RGB to CMYK in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, rgb, arcgis-10.6

**Is there a way to change the default colour palette in ArcMap?** Currently, for each symbol, I have to change RGB to CMYK to choose my colour (see screenshot). This is pretty annoying since all my colours are in CMYK.

[image]

I also had a look at the utility tool `AdvancedArcMapSettings.exe` (more details in [ArcMap Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/administer/advanced-arcmap-settings-utility.htm)) but it doesn't provide an option.

Comment: I dont know if this is still the case with 10.6 but version 9.3 was working only in RGB, meaning that internally all color where stored as RGB (the CMYK entered in the selector where converted to RGB, and converted again to CMYK at export if you choose that option...). So if CMYK value are important to you check if 10.6 actually work with CMYK value, if not check that the double conversion doesn't introduce (too much) error.

Comment: More on arcgis, RVB and CMYK here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113161/why-do-cmyk-colours-in-arcmap-not-match-those-in-adobe-products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research by myself and it seems that it's not really possible (at least not what I hoped for):

- [FAQ: Can the color space be set to HSV or CMYK by default in ArcMap?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010297)

Defining own styles for all ESRI symbols is definitively a bigger hassle than always change RGB to CMYK to select a colour...